# How to get Meteor's MongoDB URL from javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm writing a Meteor smart package wrapper for a npm module called agenda.  Agenda naturally doesn't know that it's working with Meteor, so I need to manually give it a MongoDB URL.  I can get this URL by typing `meteor mongo -U`, but I'd like the script to automatically get it so the users of the plugin don't have to worry about changing it manually.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo url is stored in environment variable called MONGO_URL. In meteor you can access env variables with `process.env` object (on server). So you can get it from `process.env.MONGO_URL` property